# Iteration and arrays [Java] Optimizing

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have to do an excercise which says to do a programm that prints a bidimensional matrix, T(4x4), and that T[n,m] = n+m.

I did it, but now, I would like to optimize it as better as posibble.

Here is my code:

```
int T[][] = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i <T.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < T[i].length; j++) {
            T[i][j]= i+j;
            System.out.print(T[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can't make your code runs faster than this, maybe to look prettier, yes. ;)

Comment: There is a way to run it faster. Use StringBuilder for all output, and then once use System.out.println()

Comment: The most expensive operation I see (except for I/O) is building a new String with `T[i][j]+" "` while you have at your disposal `System.out.print(int i)`.

Comment: well, using StringBuilder, what im doing is saving memory right? so also doing it faster?

Answer (score -3):

I red that a Fast Enumeration is faster than a normal for loop and saw a couple benchmarks that proofed it in different languages on different blogs, but thats just what I red on the web... :-)

So

for (Object o : arrayOfSomething) {
}

would be faster... Than yours.

Comment: Your claim is unsupported. It's also plain wrong. And "Fast Enumeration" is Objective-C, not Java.

Comment: Yes Fast Enumeration is obj C, I m a obj C Developer, so I just named it so... I meant For In, or For each loop should be faster than a normal for loop... Thats what I saw on benchmarks in any programming Language

Comment: The code piece I posted in my Answer is also Java code, not obj. C